Why does the pulley rotate clock wise if the slack force $F_s$ is less than the tension force $F_t$?
I am trying to understand the physics in a pulley system, specifically in a belt over a belt drive.
In this link: https://www.tec-science.com/mechanical-power-transmission/belt-drive/centrifugal-forces/
the forces acting on this belt drive are broken down and separated as the tension force (Ft) and the slack force (Fs). I understand that the friction force between the belt and wheel are what cause rotation, but what I do no understand is why the pulley rotate counter-clockwise if the tension force (Ft) is greater than the slack force (Fs) why does the pulleys rotates counter-clockwise? Shouldn't the pulley rotate in the Ft direction (clockwise) or the direction of the most force? But instead it rotates in the Fs direction as shown in their model. Why is that the case?

Also as an aside, imagine we are looking at the pin in the middle that holds the wheel. Assuming it does not rotate, it would feel forces equal to the tension and slack forces holding the belt in place right?

Are you ignoring the motor torque? If the motor went dead, then the pulley would reverse direction until the two tensions equalized.


the forces acting on this belt drive are broken down and separated as the tension force (Ft) and the slack force (Fs).

I think the text refers to them as "tight-side force" and "slack-side force".  Both of them manifest as tension in the belt.

I understand that the friction force between the belt and wheel are what cause rotation

They affect rotation.   They transfer forces from one pulley to the other.   But it may be incorrect to say they "cause" rotation.

Shouldn't the pulley rotate in the Ft direction (clockwise) or the direction of the most force?

Which pulley?   There are 2.   The force diagram is showing how the force of tension is acting on the left pulley.   But not shown is any driving torque of the engine.   Presumably that torque is turning the (left) pulley counter-clockwise, and the rotation it causes is creating differential forces on the belt.
Yes if those forces from the belt were the only torques on the left pulley, it would rotate clockwise.

Look at the equations of motion for the two pulleys. Only the net torque is important as the center of mass is fixed in space for both pulleys.

By convention (+) torque and motion is counter clock-wise.
For the motor side the rotational equations of motion are
$$ T_{\rm m} - R_{\rm m} ( F_{\rm t} - F_{\rm s} )  = I_{\rm m} \ddot{\theta}_m $$
and for the loaded side
$$ -T_{\rm d} + R_{\rm d} ( F_{\rm t} - F_{\rm s} )  = I_{\rm d} \ddot{\theta}_d $$
Additionally the kinematic constraint $R_{\rm m} \ddot{\theta}_{\rm m} = R_d \ddot{\theta}_{\rm d}$ allows for the solution
$$ \ddot{\theta}_m = \frac{R_{\rm d} ( R_{\rm d} T_{\rm m} - R_{\rm m} T_{\rm d})}{I_{\rm m} R_{\rm d}^2 + I_{\rm d} R_{\rm m}^2}$$
$$ \ddot{\theta}_d = \frac{R_{\rm m} ( R_{\rm d} T_{\rm m} - R_{\rm m} T_{\rm d})}{I_{\rm m} R_{\rm d}^2 + I_{\rm d} R_{\rm m}^2}$$
and
$$ F_{\rm t} - F_{\rm s} = \frac{I_{\rm d} R_{\rm m} T_{\rm m} + I_{\rm m} R_{\rm d} T_{\rm d}} {I_{\rm m} R_{\rm d}^2 + I_{\rm d} R_{\rm m}^2} $$
As you can see when $ T_{\rm m}/R_{\rm m} \gtrapprox T_{\rm d}/R_{\rm d}$ then the motor overpowers the tension and the pulley rotates in a CCW fashion. But when the motor torque is $T_{\rm m}/R_{\rm m} \lessapprox T_{\rm d}/R_{\rm d}$ the tension is not overcome and the pulley indeed moves to relieve the tension in the CW direction.

This makes a lot of sense, thank you a lot Alex!

@Alan - I made a mistake above since the rot. acceleration of the two pulleys is not the same. But the concept still stands. I will update the answer if I have time.
